# Does DevExpress Have Webcam Control for WPF

Tags: devexpress, webcam

I have no experience with DevExpress so I want to know if it has a WebCam control for WPF that allow me to capture a photot from a digital camera?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, DevExpress offers the [Camera Control](https://docs.devexpress.com/WPF/DevExpress.Xpf.Editors.CameraControl) for WPF applications, allowing for the capture of images from webcams.